# Missing animation when moveRowAtIndexPath to off-screen indexPath

Tags: ios, animation, tableview

I used `[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath];` to move a row to an new `indexPath` with animation.

When the `indexPath` and `newIndexPath` are both on-screen, which means contained in `[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]`, the animation works well. But if one of them are off-screen, then there's no animation and the next cell will slightly jump before moving up.

Is there any way to make it animate when moving to an off-screen indexPath?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same problem!

Comment: @TimArnold not yet since this feature changed in our product, I think the only way is init a cell by yourself and animate with it.